# How many different countries operate a satellite?

Tags: artificial-satellite, communication-satellite, international-politics

Looking over the list of recent launches, I find communication satellites for countries who do not have their own space program. How many different countries operate a satellite as of 2018? Is that number public?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite#First_satellites_of_countries) shows all the countries which have, to date, launched satellites - a total of 88. Note that some of these countries no longer exist as a single country (eg. Czechoslovakia), have changed (Soviet Union), are dependencies (Jersey) or are somewhat controversial ([Asgardia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asgardia_(nation))).

Only [12 countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite#Launch-capable_countries) have natively developed their own launch systems, so all the remaining countries have used foreign or private launch services.

**Speculation on non-public launches:**

It is *very* unlikely that any countries have managed to launch orbital payloads *in secret* on their own due to the obvious problems of trying to hide a rocket launch. However, it seems more possible that a country not on the list has operated a satellite in secret by using a foreign launch provider.

Comment: The last point is interesting. Might that in fact involve *three parties?* The secret operator, the launch provider, and the *satellite owner?* Or would it be two parties, and the secret operator was in fact the owner? It sounds confusing I know.

Comment: @uhoh very good question and one I expect we'll never have answered! Imagine if NASA and Roscosmos were secretly spying on each other with their own satellites that they secretly launched for each other. I smell a conspiracy ;)

Comment: Well, a practical approach would be to use a foreign company as a cover / middleman. To the world it looks like a domestic launch of a, say, commercial weather/research satellite made by a domestic company, while in fact it's a spy satellite was made by a different country and is operated for their benefit by the shell company.

Comment: Also, don't forget satellites sometimes change owners. For a smaller company   purchase of an existing, "used" satellite at, say, half the planned lifetime may be more beneficial than launching their own - while the seller launches a new, upgraded one (e.g. moving from analog to digital sat TV). That way a country that never launched, built or commissioned one, becomes an owner/operator of a satellite.